# For a Cantor set $\mathcal{C} \subset S^3$ such that $\pi_1(S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C})=0$, prove $S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C}$ can be split by a sphere.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, low-dimensional-topology

I'm working from the paper [*Cantor Sets in $S^3$ with Simply Connected Complements*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/016686418690060X) by Richard Skora.

On page 184 the second sentence states that any Cantor set $\mathcal{C} \subset S^3$ such that $\pi_1(S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C}) = 0$, prove $S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C}$ can be split by a sphere (i.e. for any distinct $p,q \in S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C}$, there is a pl $2$-sphere $S$ embedded into $S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C}$, such that only one of $p$ or $q$ lies in the interior of $S$, and the other in its exterior).

The paper provides two hints; that we should apply the Hurewicz Isomorphism Theorem and the Sphere Theorem.

By the hypothesis, and the Hurewicz Isomorphism Theorem we can see that $\tilde{H}_i(S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C}) = 0$ for $i \in \{ 0,1 \}$. We also have that $\tilde{H}_2(S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C}) \cong \pi_2 (S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C})$.

If I can prove that $\pi_2 (S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C}) \neq 0$, then use of the Sphere Theorem of Papakyriakopoulos enables us to split the two distinct points $p$ and $q$ by an embedding of a $2$-sphere.

My question then is how we prove that $\tilde{H}_2(S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C}) \neq 0$; I had two separate ideas for this - none of which have come to any fruition:

1. If we consider $S^3 \setminus \{p_0, p_1, p_2, ..., p_n \}$ then this is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of $n$ $2$-spheres. I'm not therefore sure whether we are able to stretch this to a Cantor set to claim it is homotopy equivalent to an infinite wedge of circles, so has a non trivial $\tilde{H}_2(S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C})$; seeing as, for example, the Cantor set could have positive Lebesgue measure?
2. To use a Mayer-Vietoris sequence - I'm not sure quite how the sequence would arise; I've tried a few different approaches, but I thought maybe we could take an $n$-cell which contains $\mathcal{C}$, however I'm not sure we can ensure this exists, because I think $\mathcal{C}$ isn't necessarily bound in $S^3$?

Thanks for your time reading this post!

Comment: I'm wondering if the hint is sufficient. Perhaps one also needs Alexander Duality to get enough nontrivial classes in $H_2(S^3 - \mathcal{C})$.

Comment: @LeeMosher are all the conditions satisfied to be able to use Alexander duality though? You need either $\mathcal{C}$ or its complement in $S^3$ to be compact and locally contractible but I can't see this holding for either subspace, even if we try to replace one with a homotopy equivalent subspace which does satisfy the conditions.

Comment: I was thinking about the version of Alexander duality that uses some variant of Cech cohomology for $H^0(\mathcal{C})$ (as in Spanier's book on Algebraic Topology). I think that, $S^3 - \mathcal{C}$ being open, you can use ordinary homology for it.

Comment: You can probably tell by my various hedging words that I am unsure about all of this, but I'm reasonably confident.

Comment: @LeeMosher sorry to be a pain - but my understanding of Cech Cohomology is rather limited; how would I apply the theory from Spanier's book (which I have in front of me) to this scenario, for $H_2(S^3 \setminus \mathcal{C}$?

Comment: @DanielRust - in this book:

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=bhNxPQExK_MC&pg=PA271&lpg=PA271&dq=alexander+duality+cech+cohomology&source=bl&ots=rVIUn5SoIB&sig=o4sC0Hwd3xSLdzU2wbdyqYoz7ZE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=i1PrU-byNMim0QWg-ICoAw&ved=0CFoQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=alexander%20duality%20cech%20cohomology&f=false

Theorem 5.7 looks like it may be the Theorem Lee was referring to; do you have any idea how I can calculate the zeroth reduced Cech Cohomology of any Cantor set?

Comment: @StephenNand-Lal I didn't see any of the new discussion after my comment so sorry for any late replies (thanks for the ping, it's an interesting question). The generalised Alexander duality for Cech cohomology does get rid of the problem I mentioned so that's good! With regard to your quesiton about how to calculate Cech cohomology, probably the most important result of Cech cohomology to remember is that the Cech cohomology of an inverse limit of spaces is isomorphic to the direct limit of the Cech cohomologies of the individual spaces (with maps being the induced maps on cohomology).

Comment: For a Cantor set, that means that if $\mathcal{C}$ is a Cantor set, then it is homeomorphic to the 'middle thirds' Cantor set which can be built as an inverse limit in the usual way by inclusions $i_n\colon C_{n+1}\to C_n$ of smaller and smaller spaces which you get by removing the middle thirds, then ninths, then twenty-sevenths, etc. This means that

Comment: $\check{H}_0(\mathcal{C})\cong\check{H}_0(\displaystyle{\lim_{\leftarrow}} (C_n, i_n))\cong \displaystyle{\lim_{\rightarrow}} (H_0(C_n),i^*_n))\cong \displaystyle{\lim_{\rightarrow}} (\mathbb{Z}^{2^n},i^*_n))\cong\bigcup_{n}\mathbb{Z}^{2^n}\cong\mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ (hopefully haven't made a mistake). I implicitly used the result here that the Cech cohmology of a space homotopy equivalent to a CW complex is isomorphic to the singular/cellular cohomology of the space, that's why the cech symbol disappeared over the $H$.

Comment: Given this result, and using the generalised duality theorem, this means that $\check{H}_2 (S^3\setminus \mathcal{C}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{\omega}$ for any Cantor set in $S^3$. The next step then would be to use this to tell you about the singular cohomology of $S^3\setminus\mathcal{C}$. Given that this space isn't homotopy equivalent to a CW-complex, as far as I know, there still seems to be some work that needs to be done.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, you do not need the Chech cohomology, just a little bit of analysis. Namely, start with the characteristic function $\chi: C\to \{0,1\}$ of a proper clopen subset of $C$. Then, by the Tietze-Urysohn extension theorem, the function $\chi$ will extend continuously to a map $S^3\to [0,1]$. Then you can modify the extension to make it smooth outside of $C$: $f: S^3\to {\mathbb R}$. Now, use Sard's theorem to find a regular value $t\in (0,1)$ of $f$. The hypersurface $f^{-1}(t)$ will separate $C$ and, hence, define a nontrivial element of $H_2(S^3\setminus C)$.